# Filtro no gridview, como fazer?

Tags: vb.net

Estou tentando fazer uma filtragem no meu gridview, mas não esta retornando nada no grid. Os parâmetros que passo estão corretos. Mas mesmo assim não retorna nada!

Aqui está o click do botão:

```
Private Sub btnPesquisar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPesquisar.Click

    Dim strOpcao As String
    Dim strPesquisar As String
    Dim objLivros As New ClasseLivros

    strOpcao = ddlPesquisar.SelectedValue
    strPesquisar = txtPesquisar.Text

    gvLivros.DataSource = objLivros.ObtemLivrosFiltrado(strOpcao, strPesquisar)
    gvLivros.DataBind()

End Sub
```

E aqui minha função:

```
Public Function ObtemLivrosFiltrado(ByVal strOpcao As String, ByVal strPesquisar As String) As DataSet

    Try

    Dim con As New SqlConnection(Conexao.ConnectionString)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("usp_lista_livros_filtrado", con)

    strPesquisar = String.Concat("'%", strPesquisar, "%'")

    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OPCAO", strOpcao)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAMPO_PESQUISA", strPesquisar)

    Dim ds As New DataSet()

        da.Fill(ds, "t_livros")

        Return ds

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try

End Function
```

E aqui minha procedure:

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        t_livros
    WHERE
        @OPCAO like @CAMPO_PESQUISA
    ORDER BY 
        nome_livro
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente usar SQL dinâmico dentro da sua SP. Apenas terá de alterar a forma como a sua SP faz a consulta:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = '    SELECT      *
                FROM        t_livros
                WHERE       ' + @OPCAO + ' LIKE ''' + @CAMPO_PESQUISA + '''
                ORDER BY    nome_livro'
EXEC(@SQL)
```